# Andorid/Flutter Biometric Details of EVERY user of the device

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, fingerprint, biometrics

I would like to know if there is ANY way to get a unique key/hash/mac or any sort of identifier when trying to identify a user on the app via the fingerprint authentication provided in flutter and android?

Please note we will be having multiple users accessing the same device and none of them will have their fingerprint registered on the device before using the app.

So basically can I register users using their fingerprint(get a unique value and store in my db) and have them login with the same finger next time they visit the app ?(same finger, send the unique value to my db and check if they exist)

Any guidance in this direction is appreciated. TIA!

Comment: You would need them to be actual separate users of the device (e.g., Settings > System > Multiple Users on a stock Android 10/11 device). They each get separate [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), and in there you can store some UUID that you generate yourself.

Comment: Okay, got it @CommonsWare!
Thanks for your quick response. Any idea why we cannot use the fingerprint scanner to get a UUID/Unique Fingerprint ID for each finger in Android as the hardware is already present? Am I missing something here?

Comment: "Any idea why we cannot use the fingerprint scanner to get a UUID/Unique Fingerprint ID for each finger in Android" -- because Google bans the practice. You cannot extract personally-identifying information from the biometric hardware. See https://source.android.com/security/biometric#hal-implementation

Comment: Oh, got it, makes sense now. Appreciate your time and support on this issue! Thanks once again!